# Difference between php md5() command and Linux md5pass command

Tags: php, linux, md5

The hash produced by php md5() command and linux md5pass command are different. What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: can you include example hashes for each of them

Comment: Dont know `md5pass`, but with `md5sum` I cannot reproduce your behaviour: Shell `$ md5sum
Hallo Welt
75b8cbbb833c0aab1151cba662246e24`, PHP `php > var_dump(md5('Hallo Welt'.PHP_EOL));
string(32) "75b8cbbb833c0aab1151cba662246e24"`

Comment: Not only the hashes, but the way you generate those hashes

Comment: in linux you can use `echo -n str | md5sum` which is equal to php's `<? echo md5('str'); ?>`

Answer (score 6):

Because md5pass does not create a hash for the given string, it creates a hash for the given string and a salt.

Comment: To test this you can generate the md5 hast twice for the same string. You will see that you get two different results.